# Is a port of an existing program eligible for the App Showdown?

Tags: application-development

- For example, the original program is Xlib based, and I port it to GTK3.
- What about porting my old gtk2-based app to gtk3?

Are either of these two eligible for entrance into the App Showdown?

Answer (score 4):

You can reuse small bits of old code, but the requirement is that your app must be created from scratch, so a GTK2 port to GTK3 would not qualify, as it would give you an unfair advantage over other participants who are starting something new.

That said, there are lots of [good ideas for new apps](http://www.reddit.com/r/UbuntuAppShowdown), feel free to pick one up!