# Is porting a game to Ubuntu fine for the Ubuntu App Showdown?

Tags: application-development

I created a mobile game for Android and iOS about  months ago. I am porting it to Desktop and would like to join the contest with it. Is this OK?

My other question: Is it okay to participate now or is it too late?

Answer (score 4):

No it has to be new software written from scratch.
Also see these answers:
[Can I submit an application started one year ago to the Ubuntu App Showdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156274/can-i-submit-an-application-started-one-year-ago-to-the-ubuntu-app-showdown)

[Is a port of an existing program eligible for the App Showdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152927/is-a-port-of-an-existing-program-eligible-for-the-app-showdown)